# phonegap lost of Internet connection?

Tags: phonegap-build

I created my first application through build phonegap

> document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
>
> ```
> function onDeviceReady() {
>     checkConnection();
> }
>
>
>
>
>     function checkConnection() {
>         if(navigator.network.connection.type==0)
>         {
>             window.location.href = "offline.html";
>         }
>         else if(navigator.network.connection.type=='none')
>         {
>             window.location.href = "offline.html";
>
>         }
>         else
>         {
>
> window.location.href = "http://mobile.site.com/";
>         }
>     }
> ```

All works but if I turn off the Internet and click on the open application, it gives an error of **ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED**

function **onDeviceReady** Works only when the application is first launched.

How do I redirect to a page offline.html If the Internet is disabled?